# asp gridview css border goes out of scope

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

The below is the css and asp code for the gridview.
The border are spreading out then expected. 
I tried setting **Width=100%** which worked, but I want the border to follow the size of grid instead spreading the grid view to occupy space unnecessarily.

This is an Asp Gridview with css for rounding corners

CSS:

```
    .rounded-corners {
        border: 1px solid #565656;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
}


    .Grid td, .Grid th {
        border: 1px solid #565656;
        text-align: center; 
        padding-top: 3.5px;
        padding-bottom: 3.5px;
        font-size: medium;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',     'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Source Code:

```
<div class="rounded-corners">
<div>
<table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>07:30</td>
<td>07:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>def</td>
<td>07:30</td>
<td>07:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ghi</td>
<td>07:30</td>
<td>07:30</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: I have attached the image on the top. I dont know why its not showing inline. Its an hyperlink saying "This is an Asp Gridview with css for rounding corners" @realbart

Comment: I saw the image, but I don't remember what html is generated by an asp.net gridview. You should look at the generated html in a browser, and use that for styling. Try display:inline-block

Comment: @realbart https://snag.gy/bHyxo.jpg If this helps you.

Comment: If you do "view source" in your browser, what do you see then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the grid is rendered like this:

```html
<div class="Grid" id="XXXX_gv1">
<table>
<tr><th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th><th>column 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>value 1</td><td>value 2</td><td>value 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>value 1</td><td>value 2</td><td>value 3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

so you could then style it:

```
.Grid {
    display:inline-block; /* trick to not take 100%. */
    /* alternatively: you could border .Grid>table */
    border-radius:8px;
}

.Grid>table>tbody>tr:first-row {
  /* special stuff for the first row here */
}
```

Comment: Its working bro Thanks, I just had to clear my cache. Thanks a lot appreciate your help man.

Comment: If i set the <asp:gridview> Width in percentage it still works but if I set it to certain pixels it works fine. Any solution for that?